# ASP.NET Sound / Audio Recording?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, html5-audio

I am creating a asp.net c# application (.net framework 4.5 with MVC4) in which I want to record user's response (feedback) in there voice on my question and then save that sound file on my server machine so that we can allow user to play their recorded sound again whenever he/she will want.

I have following problems

1. Record the sound of user's response in their own voice and save at server side.
2. I want to Identify the microphone is attached on users machine or not and give message to user if microphone is not attached with his/her machine.

I tried running sample suggested by at - http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html

Windows 7 Firefox 26.0 - Not working
Windows 7 Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63 m - Working
iPad Safari - Not working

I need some solution that works fine on any browser at Windows, mobiles and as well as at iPad

- Do not want to use flash player and Silverlight.

Answer (score 3):

Try this [Capturing Audio & Video in HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)

And you can check this Web RTC Demos - https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/

Comment: Thanks but as I wrote that I do not want to use JavaScript. In the given example it is using JavaScript.

Comment: @TejKiran, you have to use JavaScript, or else how would you send the client side content to server? If you do not want to use JS, then you need to have flash or silverlight etc. Your options are getting very narrowed.

Comment: @ramiramilu  Thanks. I have updated my question. I have no problem to use JavaScript.